# Split String and multiply 8

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with this. The user needs to enter a string and then I need to count the string and multiply the same string. For example, if the user entered the string The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog;
The output should look like this, The = 22% quick = 11% brown = 11% fox = 11% jumps = 11% over = 11% lazy = 11% dog = 11%

Here is my code

```
 string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        string[] arr1 = phrase.Split(' ');


        for (int a = 0; a < arr1.Length; a++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr1[a]);
        }



        Console.ReadKey();
```

The value is 22%, it was calculated using this formula, 2/9 * 100. 2 because "the" was used twice, divided by 9 because there are 9 words in the string. I am trying to compare each string to determine if they are the same but unable to do so.

Comment: So far, you have written code to split the string. You still need to write the code to deal with the words. How is that coming?

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary<string, int>`, documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/xfhwa508.aspx, alternatively you can use the `GroupBy` linq method on your array.

Comment: So you want a histogram of words. Maybe update the title to "How to get histogram of words from phrase".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obligatory LINQ version:

```
string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string[] words = phrase.Split(' ');
var wc = from word in words
         group word by word.ToLowerInvariant() into g
         select new {Word = g.Key, Freq = (float)g.Count() / words.Length * 100};
```

Comment: Dezza, if you're not familiar with LINQ, then check it out since afrischke's solution is nice and straightforward, and also because using LINQ makes coding quick and easy.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Minimal Use of `LINQ`!

```
        string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        string[] words = phrase.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var distinct_words = words.Distinct().ToArray();
        foreach (string word in distinct_words)
        {
            int count = words.Count(wrd => wrd == word);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} % ", word, count * 100 / words.Length);
        }
```

Or

```
        string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        string[] words = phrase.ToLower().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var needed_lines =  from word in words.Distinct() let count = words.Count(wrd => wrd == word) select String.Format("{0} = {1} % ", word, count * 100 / words.Length);

        foreach (string neededLine in needed_lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(neededLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using two List

```
List<String> words  = new List<String>();
List<int> weight = new List<int>();
```

As you go through your string you add only unique words to the words List and then the corresponding index of the weight list gets incremented by 1;

Then when you are done you can divide each of the weight values by the length of your string[]

As for getting the unique values you can do it by doing the following:

- Add first string to list automatically
- For every string after that do words.Contains(string[x])
- If it doesn't contain it then add it
- If it does contain it then do words.indexOf(string[x])
- then increment the corresponding index in the weight list

Comment: Thanks, hope it works for you. If it does please remember to upvote and select as answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
string phrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var parts = phrase.Split(' ');
var wordRatios = parts
                    .GroupBy(w => w.ToLower())
                    .Select(g => new{
                        word = g.Key,
                        pct = Math.Round(g.Count() * 100d / parts.Length)
                    });
```

Comment: Oh. Just the same as @afrisdhke.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 var  yourarr = phrase.Split(' ').GroupBy(word => word.ToUpper()).Select(w => ((w.Count()*100/ phrase.Split(' ').Distinct().Count())).ToString()+"%");
```